# How was the plan communicated between the killer and the director?

Tags: subete-ga-f-ni-naru

In episode 2, Yamane Yukihiro tells Nishinosono and Professor Saikawa that the director isn't there, he's off picking up Dr. Magata's younger sister, Miki.

> Nishinosono: Where did the director go?
>
> Yamane: He went to get Dr. Magata's younger sister.

However, we later learn that Miki was actually Dr. Magata all along. This means that the director was aware this is the day he would die all along. How though, was this plan between Dr. Magata and the director communicated? I understand that all communications were recorded. They also said multiple times that no one had gone in to Dr. Magata's room for 15 years, except they *did* open the door anytime they had to put a large package in.

What was the method they used to communicate this plan?

Comment: I assumed that the director was aware of the doctor's plans from the start, but I don't know if they ever got into the specifics, and I wonder if the doctor ever considered her daughter's noncompliance.

Comment: It seemed like he was not surprised that it was her instead of her daughter when she appeared on the roof. For any of this to work he had to be in on the plan but I guess that implies she had it all planned from the very beginning. That explains how the volumes went to 15 and they were in there before she was.

Comment: The daughter's death wasn't intended though. Perhaps either they had some communication after her death, or he was simply aware that he would die and wasn't too perturbed by the change in the killer's identity?